# JT effect on nitrogen

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm a safety specialist and stumbled upon the following question:
There is a nitrogen cylinder. Pressure inside is 200 bar. Temperature equals to ambient and is 0 Celsius.
As far as my understanding of physics goes, I assume that when I open the cylinder (for example to fill some vessel), the nitrogen, having its pressure dropped from 200 bar inside to 1 bar atmospheric, will definitely provide some cooling effect in the vessel or at least immediately after the cylinder valve.
How do I calculate the temperature drop over the cylinder valve?

Comment: What figures do you want to calculate?

Comment: Do you want (a) inside the cylinder or (b) immediately after the valve?

Comment: Oh, sorry.. My bad. I want to calculate the temperature of nitrogen after the valve.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.